# How to change behavior of underscore following a predefined command?

Tags: macros, equations, underscore

I like to create shortcuts for symbols I use often, and I want to change the behavior of the underscore following a custom command. For example, if I want to add a subscript, I want to change the placement of the subscript, but a subscript proceeding a command will just place it at the end. This is a minimal example of the behavior I would like to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fx}{{f(x)}}
\newcommand{\fxi}{{f_i(x)}}

\begin{document}
This is a function: $\fx$. This is the $i$th function: $\fxi$. 
I want to do this $\fx_i$ but make it look like this $\fxi$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I’d simply use `f_i(x)`, which is semantically sound and not more difficult to type

Comment: @egreg I agree. This is a simplified example to illustrate the question. I will use this for more complex expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the xparse commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fxi}{{f_i(x)}}
\NewDocumentCommand\fx{e{_}}
 {
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {f(x)}
    {f_{#1}(x)}
 }
\begin{document}
This is a function: $\fx$. This is the $i$th function: $\fxi$. I want to do 
this $\fx_i$ but make it look like this $\fxi$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was imagining. What is the e for in the new document command?

Comment: @Ralff `texdoc xparse` → "e Given as e{⟨tokens⟩}, a set of optional embellishments, each of which requires
a value.
If an embellishment is not present, -NoValue- is returned.
Each em-
bellishment gives one argument, ordered as for the list of ⟨tokens⟩ in the argument
specification. All ⟨tokens⟩ must be distinct. This is an experimental type."

Answer (score 6):

The following solution uses only TeX primitives. Using `\futurelet` you can test if the next character is `_`.

```
\def\fx{\futurelet\next\fxA}
\def\fxA{\ifx\next_\expandafter\fxB\else f(x)\fi}
\def\fxB_#1{f_{#1}(x)}

\def\fxi{f_i(x)}

This is a function: $\fx$. This is the $i$th function: $\fxi$. 
I want to do this $\fx_i$ but make it look like this $\fxi$.
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the advantage of using only tex primitives in contrast to new command?

Comment: @Ralff (if I understood correctly, not putting words in wipet's mouth)  personal preference. For simplicity, so the user can understand the inner working. Maybe read http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html for some more information.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility: Define a macro called, say, `\fx`, which takes a single, optional argument that's empty by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\fx}[1][]{f_{#1}(x)} % 1 optional argument; default: no arg.

\begin{document}
A basic function:   $\fx$

The $i$th function: $\fx[i]$

The $n$th function: $\fx[n]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This would solve my problem although I prefer modifying the underscore operator directly (as the usage is more intuitive to me)